# AngularJS: Catching response from server in API call in controller that did not orginate from angular view

Tags: angularjs

I am setting up a registration page where after the user submits, they are emailed an activation link. When they click on the activation link in the email, I want the account get activated on the server and then I want my angularJS controller to catch the response from the server. I got the activation part working, but I am unsure on how to catch the response from my server since the call to the server did not originate from an angular view, but from an email.

Comment: Keep your activation link as an angular page with a controller. The link is nothing but a part of your website view. On the page load activate a controller's post method using promise and on completion of the promise you will get response.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I have posted a sample. Please Check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try out the below code:**

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="activationCtrl as vm">
<h3>{{vm.activationSuccessMessage}}</h3>
<div>
```

Controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('your moduleName',[])
    .controller('activationCtrl',activationCtrl);

   activationCtrl.$inject = ['$http'];

   function activationCtrl($http)
   {
      var vm = this;

      vm.activationSuccessMessage = "";

      var param = {}; //if any
       $http.post('api/Users/Activate', param)
         .then(function(response)
          {
              //Success - Do what you need to do.
              vm.activationSuccessMessage = "Activation Successful";

           }, function(response){
              //Fail - Handle it.
              vm.activationSuccessMessage = "Activation failed";
          });   
   }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great after some slight modifications. I change the link to make the server call via angularJS view/controller like you posted instead of making a direct call to the server from the link.

Comment: Good to know that it helped you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activation page controller on load.

```
//Get activation value however you want to do that.
var activationToken = ValueFromURLSomehow.

//Can keep it simple, with a $http request directly in controller, or use a service.
$http.get('api/Account/Activate',{params{token:activationToken}}).then(function(response){
  //Success - Do what you need to do.

}, function(response){
  //Fail - Handle it.
});
```